# Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, installation

I installed windows 10 on my computer.

Every time I restart my computer, my all new files disappear
and my desktop is empty!!!

Is it a bug or setting issues?

How can I restore my files back

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Test RAM with `memtest86+`.

Comment: If you find any .exe  file or file without extension  at    C:/User/user_name/App data/Local  Location then delete it .

Comment: Also, clean all your Temp and Temporary Internet folders as wel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You somehow corrupted your explorer.exe or changed a registry setting :**
If you corrupted explorer.exe, best bet is to do a repair or system restore.

**To check if explorer.exe is set to your shell:**

Ctrl+Alt+Del to bring up task manager. Click File>Run new Task. 
Type REGEDIT, click ok.
Click the plus sign (navigate through) entries:

-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

-SOFTWARE

-MICROSOFT

-WINDOWS NT

-CurrentVersion

Click the folder **WINLOGON**
in the box to your right, find the **entry Shell**.

If the data correspondig to it is not **Explorer.exe**, double click Shell and modify it to Explorer.exe.
Close the registry,

Ctrl+Alt+Del to bring up Task Manager. 
File>New Task. Type explorer,

click ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think something is gone wrong by the installation. You can look for the files in C:/users/"you username"/desktop if they arent show there you can try other users in the /user/ directory. Maybe you have a bit of luck and the files are stored by the wrong user by some weird reason.

In the most cases the best solution is to reinstal Windows 10. I think it is faster than looking for an solution. (when you havent install a lot of software)

How you can restore your windows (clean instal) it is explained in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzTNjs8k15Q

Make sure you have an backup from your data ;-)
(sorry for bad english, iam from holland ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

yes it looks like the installation process has not been taken place properly without any interruptions.
The most convenient solution in  my experience is:-

1.search locally 'recovery options'through windows 10 search icon on the left bottom corner
 2.click "get started" button under "reset my pc".
 3.select the option "keep my files".

then once you are safely back in windows 7, again start the process of updating to windows 10 in a fresh manner WITH the pc plugged in to power and with a stable internet connection.